# Stream-y Implementation of Stream.foldRight

Tags: scala

I'm working on a [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) exercise to `implement foldRight on a Stream`.

Before getting to that exercise, let me show how I've implemented `foldLeft`.

```
  def foldLeft[A, B](as: Stream[A])(z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B  = {
    def go(bs: Stream[A], acc: B) : B = bs match {
       case x #:: xs => go(xs, f(acc, x))
       case Stream() => acc
    }
  }
```

My understanding is that, via `#::`, I'm executing the fold in a tail-recursive **and** stream-y fashion, i.e. the tail isn't fully evaluated.

However, when I thought of how to implement `foldRight`, I figured I could simply do:

`stream.reverse.foldLeft(monoid.zero)(monoid.op)`

However, calling `reverse` will result in full evaluation of the stream:

```
scala> val x = Stream(1,2,3)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> x.reverse
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(3, 2, 1)
```

How can I **stream-ily** implement `foldRight`?

Comment: https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/laziness/Stream.scala#L70

Comment: Thanks, Noah. I'll check out github before I post another `how did FP in Scala do this` question.

Comment: No problem, it's a great resource :)